# Simple javascript line behaving differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to constantly check for modifications on a page MainContainer dimensions and when that happens I'll fix its dimensions to be bigger than the biggest element inside it (wraps all elements).

If there are other ways of doing it is not really my concern. What is bothering me is the effect of changing one line.

My code is:

```
var pageMaxWidth = 0;
var pageMaxHeight = 0;
(function fixWidth()
{
 var intervalCounter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var intervalMaxWidth = 0;
        var intervalMaxHeight = 0;
        $("#MainContainer table").each(function(index,elem){
            if($(elem).width()>intervalMaxWidth)
            {
                intervalMaxWidth=$(elem).width();
                //console.debug("new interval width");
            }
            if($(elem).height()>intervalMaxHeight)
            {
                intervalMaxHeight=$(elem).height();
                //console.debug("new interval height");             
            }
        });
        if(pageMaxWidth!=intervalMaxWidth)//I'm the referred if
        {
            $("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth);
            pageMaxWidth=intervalMaxWidth;
            console.debug("width fixed");
        }
        if(pageMaxHeight!=intervalMaxHeight)
        {
            $("#MainContainer").height(intervalMaxHeight);
            pageMaxHeight=intervalMaxHeight;
            console.debug("height fixed");
        }
        },500);
})();
```

If on the commented if (I'm the referred if) I change:

```
$("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth);
```

to

```
$("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth+40);
```

and run the script in Chrome it will always increment the MainContainer width, meaning it will always evaluate to true`pageMaxWidth!=intervalMaxWidth`. How can that happen if I didn't change the intervalMaxWidth value? But it is actually added 40 because I checked by debugging through the console.
In FireFox that doesn't happen

Comment: Doesn't intervalMaxWidth get changed here? intervalMaxWidth=$(elem).width();

Comment: Try to apply the following CSS to your `#MainContainer` element: `position:relative; width:auto; height:auto;`

Comment: "If there are other ways of doing it is not really my concern...", well it might be my concern if I was using your web site ;) Little things like this (something running every 500ms) can add up. Would the "onresize" event or the above css solution be much nicer to the browser?

Comment: If you want to keep inline elements from wrapping, you can also add `white-space: nowrap;` to your CSS

Comment: @Derek: yes it is but after changing the pageMaxWidth to be equal to interMaxWidth the commented if shouldn't be run again...and it's not unless I do the $("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth+40); with the +40, why is this changing the intervalMaxWidth?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this between FF and Chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/rx5vx/2/.  If what you're looking to do is get the max width/height of all of your tables and apply that width/height back to #MainContainer, what you have works properly.  Resize the Display pane at the jsfiddle to see the numbers update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of is that the line:

```
if($(elem).width()>intervalMaxWidth)
```

is being executed for one of the elements and is modifying intervalMaxWidth inside the if condition.

Comment: but if I only change the width of #MainContainer which shouldn't be caught inside the jquery selection, right? Besides if I do $("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth); it's ok but $("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth+40); evaluates to true the condition in the next run?

Comment: Could it be that $("#MainContainer").width(intervalMaxWidth+40); is causing an auto resize of the elements inside MainContainer and causing $('#MainContainer table') related if condition to evaluate to true?

Comment: so every time I add 40 the elements inside try to catch up and then I add another 40 and they try to catch up again and again...always changing the intervalMaxWidth... and goes on?

Comment: It's just a theory. I am no expert on html/browser related stuff so I might be wrong...

Comment: You could use console.log statements to see exactly what's going on.